# Python PHPSESSID missing

Tags: python, cookies, sessionid

I'm trying to get PHPSESSID. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
k = requests.get('http://index.hu')
for cookie in k.cookies:
    print (cookie.name, cookie.value)
```

Results:

```
('INX_CHECKER2', '1')
('mobile_detect', 'desktop')
```

When I open the page it has PHPSESSID in cookies.

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your python code. What happens if you try to output `k.cookies['PHPSESSID']`?

Comment: OK, I tried my suggestion, but it can't find the key 'PHPSESSID' and all the other cookies, except those 2 you already have got.

Comment: maybe server doesn't use PHPSESSID on main page. Delete cookies in browser and open page in brower again.

Comment: or maybe server checks user-agent header and gives ID only to client with correct user-agent header.

Comment: @furas Yes, there must be something. It isn't an issue with the requests library. I checked with JavaScript in the console and got 18 cookies.

Comment: @furas Same with proper user-agent header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHPSESSID is not set by the main page as was already discovered in the comments of your question.
It is set by making a request to http://index.hu/ident

So by altering your code to:

```
import requests
k = requests.get('http://index.hu/ident')
for cookie in k.cookies:
    print (cookie.name, cookie.value)
```

I get the following results:

```
INX_CHECKER2 1
PHPSESSID 7hq1o1rqe9ft78h0d2agelcf90
inx_checker2 1
```